# Почему поисковик индексирует несуществующую страницу сайта?

Tags: seo, поиск, поисковые-системы

Пишу в поисковой строке Яндекса *site:[http://мой-домен.ru](http://xn----htbdnodicd.ru)* и вижу ссылки на файлы, которые я удалил из сайта еще давно. Например, еще неделю назад у меня было несколько html страниц на сайте, но я их удалил, и сейчас у меня ни в одной директории сайта нет файлов разрешения html, но поисковик показывает их (Яндекс даже в сниппет добавляет текст, ранее содержащийся на уже удаленной странице)
И еще я вижу в результатах поиска ныне существующие страницы, в которых мною написаны title и desription, но Яндекс почему-то сам выбирает title и desription. Не понимаю, почему

Подскажите, что делать

Comment: Может быть яндекс просто не успел удалить страницы из выдачи. Посмотрите в Яндекс Вебмастер.

Comment: description давно никто не использует вроле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это потому что ещё не было обновления индекса. Со временем удалённые страницы сами исчезнут из выдачи. Аналогично должны обновиться title и description.

Периодичность обновления индекса определяется поисковиком самостоятельно. Поэтому точные сроки здесь назвать к сожалению не получится.

Comment: я думаю, так и есть. спасибо